# How to import blending animations into Blender?

Tags: animation, import, three.js

I'm trying to import a js [file](http://threejs.org/examples/models/skinned/marine/marine_anims.js) with blending animations into Blender(v2.65) using the three.js(r66) importer, but it seems that the importer plug-in is not working properly, because nothing is shown in the scene. I tried to convert the js into an obj file and then import it into Blender, but only the mesh was imported, the blending animations were not imported. Can someone help me please?

Three.js (r69) importer/exporter for Blender: [link](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender)

Comment: I've never used the three.js importer, but if you could post the js file it may be helpful. Also, is animation part of what gets imported? May seem like a silly question, but if animation is not supported by the add-on, then that could be the reason.

Comment: I edited my post with the js file, it's a three.js example. And yes, the animations are part of what I want to import. If the animation is not supported by the add-on, then how can I import the animations? Is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: Thanks for posting the .js file. Where can I download the three.js import/export add-on? I searched but didn't find any download page.

Comment: I edited my post with the add-on.

Comment: I downloaded the add-on but couldn't get it to install. I pointed Blender to the .zip file and the folder got unzipped to the scripts directory, but when I search "three" from the add-ons menu no such add-on appears listed. I also tried browsing all the Import-Export add-ons but it's not there. But even without getting it to work I may have found the problem - this from the page you linked to: "IMPORTER: Currently there is no import functionality available."

Comment: You have to install Blender (v2.65) and download three.js (r66) [link](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/releases/tag/r66). After that, you have to copy and paste the folder "io_mesh_threejs" inside the directory utils>exporters>blender>2.65>scripts>addons to the directory scripts>addons, where the Blender installation is.

Comment: Then, you have to open Blender>File>User Preferences>Addons. Search for three.js plugin and enable it by checking the box in the upper right corner. Then, click File>Import>Choose the extension.

Comment: Thanks for the additional installation details, but I'm pretty certain the problem is that .js import functionality is not supported. Seems this add-on is currently designed for exporting only.